# Reference Library for all C# .NET methods

Tags: c#, .net

There are a lot of built in methods and properties in C# and .NET, such as `Trim()` and `Length()`.  Where can I find a complete list of these methods and properties for built-in types?

Comment: Are you talking just about strings?

Comment: Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/vcsharp/default(en-us).aspx

Comment: There are enought functions in the framework to fill an entire live... O_O

Comment: I never counted, but I think the .net framework has thousands of methods, if not more... You might find [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) useful here.

Comment: @arash: MSDN *is* the "list"...

Comment: Why the "not a real question" closure votes? For a novice programmer, or someone coming from a language that offers a wide set of functionality by default it's a not-unreasonable question. Perhaps it could've been worded better, but I'm sure Arashs english is better than most of our Iranian...!

Comment: @Rob "Not a real question" because the scope of the question is too large and doesn't ask a definitive question. The real answer is "there are no functions in C# it's all libraries"

Comment: I completely disagree with this question being closed. It's obvious (to me at least -- maybe I'm wrong) that the OP is coming from a background in a language like PHP or VB, where there **is** a set of methods built in to the language, not belonging to any class. This is a real question and none of the answers really clarified this point for the OP, which is sad to me.

Comment: @Dan Tao, I've also voted to re-open.
@Ian, then explain that to the OP and try to help them improve their question. A drive-by close vote without so much as a comment helps neither the OP, or anyone else who may ask a similar poorly worded question in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need a reference of the .NET class library and all the classes and methods it provides, **MSDN** is almost definitely the single most useful online resource — See e.g. [**.NET Framework Class Library Overview**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfa3fa08.aspx) (introduction) and [**.NET Framework Class Library**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229335.aspx) (reference library).

---

If all that you need is a reference of .NET **string methods**, again:

- Go on MSDN
- Find the reference page for the `System.String` class
- Browse to the bottom and follow the link to the class members page: [**there you are**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_members.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

.Net doesn't have "functions", everything you've listed is a method that is called on an object.  Some are called on instances of objects, and some are called on the static type of the object.

Having a list of all functions would be pointless without knowing what objects they are related to.

There are also many overloads for methods, so they can be called with different parameters.

So what you really need (if you want them all) is a table of Object, Static or instance method, Method, Overloads.

Answer (score 4):

You can also browse the methods from Object browser using the visual studio 2005 or latest versions.